# Ansible List acces from value var

Tags: list, variables, ansible

On Ansible, how to acces to value of dict from value in other var?

Example:

```
 #Var:
 class_to_traitement: a
 #Declare list:
 students:
   a: 10
   b: 20
 
 debug:
   msg: "{{ students }}.0.{{ class_to_traitement }}"
```

Result:

```
"msg: [{u'a': u'10', u'b': u'20' }].0.a
```

Desired result:
**"msg: [{u'a': u'10'}]"**

Thanks All!

Comment: `msg: "{{ students[class_to_traitement] }}"`

Comment: |___ CORRECT! Thank's a lot

Comment: Glad to help. I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg: "{{ students[class_to_traitement] }}"`